# Cells per category in R terra

Tags: r, terra

On a categorical SpatRast object, how do I efficiently return a count of cells per factor level? Equivalent to e.g. GRASS [r.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.stats.html) with flag 'c'

```
summary(x, size = ncell(x))
```

returns a table object with the first few categories, but then lumps the rest into 'other'.

```
zonal(x, x, length)
```

works on small example rasters but has memory limits that mean it won't work on large ones. Is there another approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `help(package="terra")` you can bring up the help documents and read the function summaries. The function you are looking for is `terra::freq`

Comment: And `?terra` is also helpful. `freq` is in the same group as `zonal` and `summary`